# how to read/write text file from your local machine?

Tags: abap

```
report  try1.

class register definition.
  public section.
    methods: constructor.
class-data: read_data type pa0008-bet01,    "i tried string first, but i found this one
endclass.                                       "still doesnt work

class register implementation.
 method constructor.
  data sometext(100) value 'C:\Users\tgbtstj3\Desktop\ZzZzZz.txt'.
  open dataset sometext for input in text mode encoding default.
  do.
   read dataset sometext into read_data.
   if sy-subrc <> 0.
    exit.
   endif.
   close dataset sometext.
   write / read_data.
  enddo.
 endmethod.
endclass.

data reg type ref to register.
START-OF-SELECTION.
create object reg.
```

here is my code, i just started abap programming and wanted to make a small program to learn... but i m stuck at reading txt file from my local machine and i cant proceed...
the error says file is not open...
and exception catched by cx_sy_file_open_mode

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
data file(100) value '.\myfile'.
data num type string.
open dataset file for output in text mode encoding default.
close dataset file.
```

then change the the read_data as:

```
class-data: num type string.
```

find and change all read_data to num.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question this would be an answer to would be "How can I read a file from the application server INSTEAD OF reading it from the front-end"?

Comment: Sorry that i am beginner with abap, sorry for being new on this forum, sorry because i cannot change the question...

Comment: My intention was to invoke a "sorry that I posted wrong information and misleading code in a place where other rookies like me might be looking for useful answers in the future."

Answer (score 2):

The statement `OPEN DATASET` is used to access a file on the application server. To access the front-end, use the methods of the class `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES`. For an example, check the report `GRAPHICS_IGS_ZIPPER_DEMO`.

Comment: well, thanks for advice, but i found quicker solution for my case(thanks to you), i just created the text file into the server with using FOR OUTPUT.

Comment: That is not a solution, it's a change of the original requirement. Good luck satisfying customers that way...

Comment: customer is me, reading a file wasnt my main purpose, still i learnt where to look now if i need to, but again thanks for your help.